# Can I block or disable hotspot mode in iOS 5.1?

Tags: iphone, tethering

I'm using iPhone 4, iOS 5.1.

Can I block or disable hotspot mode in iOS 5.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Source: [Share your Internet connection with Personal Hotspot - Apple KB](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4517)